# Spaceship operator and conditional statements

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements, spaceship-operator

Quick question. Is there more elegant way to write something like this?

```
result = a <=> b

if result == 1
  # do something
elsif result == 0
  # do something else
else
  # do something else
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`case` statement](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-case):

```
case a <=> b
  when 1
    # do something
  when 0
    # do something else
  when -1
    # do something else
  else
    # return / catch error
end
```

For simple one liners you can also shorten it with `then`

```
case a <=> b
  when 1 then x = "foo"
  when 0 then y = "bar"
  when -1 then z = "foobar"
  else # return / catch error
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is more elegant, but it certainly is more direct:

```
case
when a < b
  # do A
when a > b
  # do B
else
  # do C
end
```